# How Do I Make These Buttons in a Row Instead of a Column and How Do I Scale Everything?

Tags: html, css

I am kind of new to HTML and CSS so I decided to try and make a new website. I am almost finished but the only issues that I have are that the buttons are in a column instead of a row and whenever I try to view the website in different screen sizes, the text is partially off the screen. I've tried using floats to resolve the button issue but I couldn't seem to understand the actual function and how to use it. I also have 0 clue how to fix the scaling part. Any solution and an explanation about it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #782F40;
    transition: 3s;
}

h1{
    color: white;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;

    

}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.title{
    
    font-size: 130px;
    color: #FAF9F6;
    font-weight: 700;
    

}

.subtitle{
    color: white;
    font-size: 80px;
    
}

button{
    margin:7px auto;
    display:block;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #FAF9F6;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: transform .6s;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}



button:hover{
    color:white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.03);
}


#particles-js{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="timestamp">
    <title>Julian Sanchez</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4ce3863cee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>
                <span class="title">Julian Sanchez</span><br>
                <span class="subtitle">CS @ FSU</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
                <form>   
                <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.google.com/">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></button></form>    
                        <form>   
                <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.google.com/>
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></button></form>  
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mobile view looks not good right? expecting to place the button in vertically or horizontally for different screens ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Would I Put These Buttons Side by Side and At the Center of my Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73178072/how-would-i-put-these-buttons-side-by-side-and-at-the-center-of-my-page)

Answer (score 1):

Learn flexbox it will make your life much easier.Moreover you dont need form tag for buttons.

```
 <div class="btn-group" style="display: flex; flex-direction:column" > 
        <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.google.com/">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></button>     
        <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.google.com/">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></button>
    </div>
```

Hope it Works <3

Comment: or if u dont want to use flexbox for now use "display: inline" styling on  both buttons

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I am also new to HTML but I think you can try changing the button’s display attribute from block to inline

Comment: Hi, I've tried that but it just brings the buttons to the left side and they are still vertically aligned.