# How Would I Put These Buttons Side by Side and At the Center of my Page?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I need help putting the two LinkedIn buttons side by side. They are vertically aligned right now but I don't know how to put them together side by side. I plan on adding a few more in the future, possibly 3 or 4 more but I am not yet sure. I've tried changing the display in the button to inline but this did not work for me.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #782F40;
  transition: 3s;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.title {
  font-size: 130px;
  color: #FAF9F6;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.subtitle {
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
}

button {
  margin: 3px auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FAF9F6;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: transform .6s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

#particles-js {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="timestamp">
  <title>Name</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4ce3863cee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>
        <span class="title">Name</span><br>
        <span class="subtitle">CS @ FSU</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <form>
        <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.google.com/">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin">
        </i></button>
      </form>
      <form>

        <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.google.com/>
          <i class=" fa-brands fa-linkedin "></i>
        </button>
      </form> 
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="particles-js "></div>    

<script type="text/javascript " src="particles.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript " src="app.js "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Place them inside a container (div). The container can be `display:flex` *or* the buttons could have `float:left`. The `flex` is easier I guess

Comment: He isn't nesting them. They are one after another. That is confusing.

Comment: @DavidThomas Hi, sorry about that. I am new to HTML and CSS and I was watching YouTube video on how to make buttons and I figured copy and pasting the form with the buttons inside was how you would include multiple buttons.

Comment: @ITgoldman: so he is; thank you for the correction. Julian, my apologies, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place them inside a container (div). The container can be display:flex or the buttons could have float:left. The flex is easier I guess.

Note: I made you a snippet because you had some issues in your HTML.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #782F40;
  transition: 3s;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.title {
  font-size: 130px;
  color: #FAF9F6;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.subtitle {
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
}

button {
  margin: 3px auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FAF9F6;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: transform .6s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

#particles-js {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.buttons-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="timestamp">
  <title>Name</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4ce3863cee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>
        <span class="title">Name</span><br>
        <span class="subtitle">CS @ FSU</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <form>
        <div class="buttons-container">
          <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.google.com/">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
                    </button>

          <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.google.com/">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
                    </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="particles-js"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="particles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, this helped me out. If you don't mind me asking, what was wrong with my HTML?

Comment: No sorry, it's my mistake. Your HTML seem fine now. So pay attention I changed something with the `<forms>` around the buttons. Do you want me to revert that? It might slightly affect the solution because `flex` container will align only its immediate children.

Comment: No this solution works perfectly. I watched a YouTube video on how to make buttons and they included form tag for each button they made so I really didn't understand how it worked, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use either flexbox or create an `<ul>`

For flexbox wrap them in a `<div class="btn">` and in css set btn to `display: flex;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with using Bootstrap easily, but if you don't want to use it there are several different ways. I can give one of them. You can add this code on your style part.

```
div {
    display: flex;
}
```

This code affects all div's but you can use id or class for prevent this.